# Set comparison with different types on either side

Tags: pascal

The following code, taken from Gnu Pascal test code, will compile nicely in Free Pascal. And I can understand how it works.

```
var s1 : set of 0..255;
    s2 : set of 64..128;
    ok : boolean;

procedure p1;
begin
  if s1 = s2 then begin 
    writeln('failed1');
    ok := false;
  end;
end;
```

However, I'm slightly curious what the rules are for set compatibility and what you can expect. For example:

```
program p;

var
   a : set of 0..10;
   b : set of 20..100;
   s : integer;

begin
   b := [20];
   a := [];
   if a = b then 
     writeln('a')
   else
     writeln('b');
end.
```

This prints 'b'. But if I have two empty sets (`b := [];`) then they are considered equal.

I'm just trying to get my head around how this actually gets implemented.

(What I'm kind of thinking is that the two sets are converted to the union of the ranges, so `set of 0..100` are created, and two temporaries from `a` and `b` as `set of 0..100`, and then comparison is done those temporaries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets with integers as base type (the type after the `set of`) are always compatible.

Your assumption is correct: in general both sets are converted to temporaries with common ranges and then the temporaries are compared. The conversion is done by calls to `fpc_varset_load`.

If you are interested in more details, the code which decides how to convert the sets, is located in nadd.pas (see [1](http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/compiler/nadd.pas?revision=32902&view=markup)) starting at line 1593.

Comment: Thanks. Since I'm writing my own compiler, I'd rather not look at other people's compiler code too much.

Comment: If you're writing a compiler you might need a written specification of the language your compiler processes. In the case of Pascal you might consider ISO/IEC 7185 (also called Standard Pascal).

Comment: @Stuart: Yes, but reading the spec doesn't actually explain what happens with different set types (at least not my reading of the spec - and the above test is not part of the "iso7185pat.pas" that I'm currently running [and passing, aside from the goto from a function into "main"]). And it wasn't a problem in my compiler until I started reducing unnecessarily large sets - if all sets are 512 or 1024 bits long, regardless of content, it's not a problem.

Comment: [At least not until you get to `set of -215..117;` combined with `set of 746..1153` or such]

Comment: What spec are you using?